# rails 4 undefined local variable rendering partial has_many_through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to display all of the comments on all of a user's posts in a has_many_through association.

routes.rb:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, :through => :posts, dependent: :destroy
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
def activity
  @user = current_user
  @posts = @user.posts
  @comments = @user.comments
end
```

activity.html.erb

```
<h4>My Activity</h4>
<ol class="posts">
  <%= render @comments.last(3) %>
</ol>
```

_comment.html.erb

```
<div class="comment" id="comment-<%= post.id %>-<%= comment.id %>">
    <%= link_to smavatar_for(comment.user), user_path(comment.user.name) %>
    <span class="user"><%= link_to comment.user.name, user_path(comment.user.name) %></span>
  <div class="comment-content">
    <%= simple_format(comment.content) %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The line `<%= render @comments.last(3) %>` in activity.html.erb gives the error

> undefined local variable or method `post' for Class

for the line `<div class="comment" id="comment-<%= post.id %>-<%= comment.id %>">` in _comment.html.erb.  I know I probably need to pass local variables to the partial, I just can't figure out how to do it. `<%= @comments.last(3) %>` instead of `<%= render @comments.last(3) %>` prints all the comment params to the view, so it's recognizing the collection.  Add `locals: { comment: @comment, post: @post }` still gets me undefined local variable post for Class, and `post: @comment.post` gets a nilClass error.  I've been all over SO and the RoR Guides backwards and forwards on rendering partials, and I'm still very unclear on what to pass when, so any help there in general is appreciated.

Comment: are you rendering posts as well in the same page? i dont see any problem on how you render comments

Comment: @Marv-C, I can render posts on the same page, and they render just fine, but I'd like this view to just render the comments a user has received from others on their posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Reference the `Post` from the `Comment` itself

Assuming every `Comment` has a `belongs_to :post` association

Call the partial using the shortcut syntax exactly as you had

```
<%= render @comments.last(3) %>
```

Inside the partial, use `comment.post` or `comment.post_id` to get `Post` data

E.g.

```
<div class="comment" id="comment-<%= comment.post_id %>-<%= comment.id %>">
    <%= link_to smavatar_for(comment.user), user_path(comment.user.name) %>
    <span class="user"><%= link_to comment.user.name, user_path(comment.user.name) %></span>
  <div class="comment-content">
    <%= simple_format(comment.content) %>
  </div>
</div>
```

## No need to use `locals` in this scenario

Notice that you tried to pass `@post` in through the `locals` option, however in your controller you have a `@posts` variable (plural), not `@post` singular.

Because each of the `Comment` records may belong to a different `Post`, there is no single option you can pass for `Post`.

The only other way to use `locals` is if you broke out the partial into a loop and rendered each `Comment` individually, e.g.

```
<% @comments.last(3).each do |comment| %>
   <%= render comment, post: comment.post %>
   <!-- OR -->
   <%= render partial: "comments/comment", locals: { comment: comment, post: comment.post } %>
<% end %>
```

Notice we still need to call `comment.post` to get the `Post` associated with the `Comment`. Because of this, it's much simpler to just use the shortcut syntax and reference the `Post` from the `Comment` within the partial.

Comment: @JimHogan Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Different perspective you just need to change `post.id` to `comment.post.id` in _comment.html.erb without pass `locals`, it more clearner and simple

```
<div class="comment" id="comment-<%= comment.post.id %>-<%= comment.id %>">
  <%= link_to smavatar_for(comment.user), user_path(comment.user.name) %>
  <span class="user"><%= link_to comment.user.name, user_path(comment.user.name) %></span>
  <div class="comment-content">
    <%= simple_format(comment.content) %>
  </div>
</div>
```

does it work?

Comment: Too bad, i lose the race :D